# Java - Which hibernate inheritance strategy is best in which case?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have a confusion on choosing a hibernate inheritance strategy under different circumstances. I have seen documentation and I know the Advantages/Disadvantages of all the strategies like Single Table, Table Per concrete class etc. But I could not figure out the best use of each strategy.
If I have a Java code containing all of the following:

- Simple inheritance
- Multiple inheritance
- Multi-Level inheritance

Which strategy should I have for each of the above cases?

Comment: I don't think that's enough information. It would likely depend on the actual case (code); how many fields are there in each and so on.

Comment: To me it's a design question, which would be best answered at [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Keep in mind that JOINs impact performance. Depending on the kind of data the tables will hold, you may want to arrange your database architecture differently.